# Find the expected total weight of 10 full containers?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is the problem. Let random variable $Y$ be the weight of an empty container. Let random variable $X$ be the weight of the contents in the container. Find the expectation and standard deviation of the total weight of ten containers, given the following information:

Standard deviation $X$: $15$ grams.

Standard deviation $Y$: $10$ grams

Mean weight $X$: $800$ grams

Mean weight $Y: 400$ grams

Here's what I did boys and girls.
Let $T$ = total weight of ten containers (including contents)
Therefore $T= 10(X+Y) = 10X+10Y$

$E(T)=E(10X+10Y) =10E(X)+10E(Y) = 12000$ grams. So far so good.

$Var(T)=Var(10X+10Y)  = 10^2(Var(X)+Var(Y))$
(I square the standard deviations to get the variances of $X$ and $Y$)

So I get an answer of $Var(T)= 32500$ grams. So my standard deviation is $180.3$ grams. This is not correct. Somebody help is doing my head in!!

(The answer is $57$ grams btw)

Which can be found by doing 10(var(X)+var(Y)) 
Which has something to do with when the variables are Independant observations. Ffs. How is one to know when Independant observations occur?

Comment: Should be easy for the math beasts on here so I would appreciate anybody who chimed in. Cheers

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please familiarise yourself with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use it to format your post to make it easier for people to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is you assume

$$T=10(X+Y)$$

that is not correct as the containers are not identical.

It should be $$T=\sum_{i=1}^{10} (X_i+Y_i)$$

Comment: Mate you absolute ledgend. The real weird thing is "when are observations not Independant?" It seems like there's never any situation where you would use the (10^2)*varX+var(Y) idea. But I guess I will see the connection the more problems I do. Love this site by the way holy moly it's gonna bump my grades up soooo much

Comment: We have to make assumptions when we do modelling in practice. IID is a common assumptions though it is not always true.

Comment: A scenario that let you use $10(X+Y)$ could be for each gram, you are being charged $\$10$. Find its variance.

Comment: Dude I love the internet thank you soo much bro. This page is just too good honestly.

Answer (score 1):

$$Var (10X + 10 Y) = 10 \cdot 225 + 10 \cdot 100 = 3250$$ so the standard deviation is $$\sqrt{3250} = 57$$ as sought.